# Using alloc and init when using a UITableViewCell from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm doing a simples app using Storyboard that a have a View with a `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCell` that do the navigation to another `UIView`.

So a have to code to populate the cell on the table view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SampleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"cai no init da cell");
    }

    GPItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Post";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.imageURL;

    return cell;
}
```

I realised that the code `if (cell == nil) { ...` never executes so I really need to do that on uses the cell from Storyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` this makes cell not nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct; that code is guaranteed to return a non-nil cell if you are using a storyboard. Also, in iOS 6, the new call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` *never* returns nil. See the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_registering_a_cell_class

Comment: Thanks man. So and what are you think about using storyboards? Should use or not?

Comment: I use storyboards sometimes, but I also know how generate my interface and my view controllers in code or using old-style nib files. Storyboards are great as long as you understand them. They are not magic. You still have to know what's really going on. Again, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_storyboards

Answer (score 0):

If you've declared your UITableViewCell in table view's prototype cells it's already allocated and just needs to be dequeued. If you're using a custom UITableViewCell subclass, then you must check if it's nil and allocate new entities when necessary.

Comment: That's not precisely right. A custom UITableViewCell subclass can still be the prototype cell from the storyboard so it will never be nil.

Comment: I don't remember saying custom cells cannot be prototyped. I said if the cell is not prototyped, it should be allocated. Context man, context.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you don't need that code when using a cell made in your storyboard.

It is probably best to remove this code so that you crash nice and early if the `identifier` you gave to the cell in interface builder and the identifier you use in code ever drift. This snippet will mask this error and just provide a cell that you most likely was not intending to  have.